# Is someone reported a video to the fbi, would the IP address be traced?

Tags: privacy, ip

Supposedly, if someone were to report a video to the fbi, if anyone watched that video, would their ip address be traced down?

Comment: That's up to the FBI

Comment: Who knows? It's probably the FBI's video.

Comment: How would someone watch the video after it was reported? Whose IP address are you concerned about, the reporter or a viewer? If concerned about the reporter, how is the video reported? If concerned about the viewer, where is the video hosted?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a criminal issue like child pornography it might well be that the FBI will track down the server and get access to the log files to track down all who watched that video. And these log files usually log IP address, browser, time etc and maybe they will also find information about logged in users and can associated actual user data with the video consumers.